# WPF: Get all named elements in Window

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, window

In XAML I have created `CustomWindow`. It contains many nested elements. Is exists simply method to get all named elements (I set names through `x:Name="SomeName"`), marked as public (I set modifier through `x:FieldModifier="public"`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no out of the box way I'm aware of. You have to browse the VisualTree using the `VisualTreeHelper` and check if they have the properties you are interrested in.

Here is a method that can do what you need :

```
public static IEnumerable<FrameworkElement> FindVisualChildren(FrameworkElement obj, Func<FrameworkElement, bool> predicate)
{
    if (obj != null)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(obj); i++)
        {
            var objChild = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(obj, i);
            if (objChild != null && predicate(objChild as FrameworkElement))
            {
                yield return objChild as FrameworkElement;
            }

            foreach (FrameworkElement childOfChild in FindVisualChildren(objChild as FrameworkElement, predicate))
            {
                yield return childOfChild;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Usage could be something like that for a check on the name only :

```
var children = FindVisualChildren((FrameworkElement)sender, o => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(o.Name));
```